# Taxes on Payment in lieu of notice (PILON) and salary overlap

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom

Assuming that someone leaves a company for a new role on the day of the payment (both companies pay on the same date monthly), there are two scenarios:

- The Payment in lieu of notice (PILON) is paid with the salary from the last month from the 1st company
- The Payment in lieu of notice (PILON) is paid with the first salary from the 2nd company

Does this overlap affect the taxes? I am aware that the Payment in lieu of notice does not take into account the pension contribution but it does include the NI and Tax payments. My current calculation to see how much NET someone will get from the Payment in lieu of notice is based on the daily payment. The salary from the first company is added and then from the daily gross payment the Tax and National Insurance are deducted. Lastly, that amount is multiplied with the holidays that are about to be paid (unused holidays).

Comment: Payment in lieu of notice is paid only by the company you are leaving, and then when they let you go without the proper advance notice. Whatever the company you are going to is paying you it should have a different name.

Comment: If someone who actually worked at HMRC was on this stackexchange they'd have 10k rep in no time 

Answer (score 1):

The PILON will just be paid with your normal rate of tax deducted, regardless of when it is paid.

It's possible that this won't turn out to be the correct rate if the overlap of salary pushes you into a new tax bracket for the year. In this case it will be corrected in future salary payments - HMRC just tells your employer your tax code, which tells them how much to deduct but nothing at all about *why* the deductions are that amount.

Comment: That is what I thought. But how can someone track the correction of the rate in future salary payments?

Comment: What do you mean "how can someone track it"? You don't need to track it, HMRC will automatically update your tax code accordingly and inform your employer. They will also send you a coding notice if they do this so you will be given the relevant information.

Comment: I think I must not be understanding what your concern / question actually is. What are you worried about or trying to figure out?

Comment: My main mission is to calculate how much the final amount of days off paid (in lieu) will be, after taxes. I found the gross number but I am not sure how to calculate the net. I just calculate it as if it was a monthly salary and deduct the tax, NI number.

Comment: So, my calculation to see the NET PILON starts here: https://www.thesalarycalculator.co.uk/salary.php where I put my salary without the pension. Then I check the daily payment (2021 Take Home) and lastly, I multiply that with the number of holidays that are going to be paid.

Comment: Are you starting the new job before the notional notice period expires, so you'll end up getting paid twice for the same days, once by your old employer and once by your new employer? If so you'll get taxed on it at your "marginal rate" of tax. I'd try using a take-home calculator for your normal pay, and for your normal pay + PILON added, and then subtract the two figures to get a rough net payment for your PILON.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica I just got a reply from the HR stating that there will be a full payment including the In Lieu during my last day. That been said, I can calculate how much NET I will be paid that day. However, like Vicky said, I am expecting a correction from the HRMC in the future salary payments (Tax reduction). Overall, in order to see the final payment In Lieu for 2021/2022 I added the accrued holidays + carried over holidays and then multiplied that number based on the NET payment per day (from the old salary). I hope I am correct on this one :)

Comment: Why are you expecting a tax *reduction* later? If the payment doesn't push you into a new tax bracket there will be no change to the tax later. If the payment does push you into a new tax bracket, you will owe more tax rather than less.

Comment: @Vicky: if it does push you into a new tax bracket on a PAYE basis, then you'd probably see a gradual refund of that extra tax over the following months - because the tax brackets are doled out on a month by month basis. Essentially you'll pay tax as if your total income for the year so far will "scale up" for the whole year, and then get some back as PAYE notices that it isn't doing that. (EDIT - I think that's exactly what you meant in your answer, but maybe I'm confused)

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica Oh I see what you mean. Yes, I think we are all talking past each other here :)

Comment: @Datacrawler you'll get a more accurate calculation by working out the gross pay for the time you are owed, and then using a salary calculator to work out what the net pay should be (as I described in an earlier comment).  Also, is this payment actually for untaken holiday rather than an part unworked notice period? It doesn't make any difference to the payment but it is a bit misleading to call it PILON then.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica I did. I basically summed the salary and the PILON and it seems that from an X amoun for the PILON I will receive only 53% due to the taxes. If I receive the PILON without taking into account the salary that month, I will then receive around 76% of it. Does that make sense though?

Comment: @Datacrawler Hard to say without exact numbers. 53% suggests you might be getting taxed on 45% on the PILON, which is the highest possible marginal tax rate. If so I'd expect you to get at least some of it back later in the year.